# Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (45, 20) but got array with shape (45, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, lstm

I have a dataframe of shape (2000,45) and I need to convert it to (2000,45,20).
Each 45 columns contains a list of 20 elements.
Please help me out with this.
The dataset looks like the following-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oFT0.png)

Comment: Please clarify the issue. Preferably include a short code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I begin, a correction in your question: 
"Each **cell** in your dataframe is a list of 20 elements"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({0: [[2, 3, 4], [1,2,3], [4, 5,6]], 1: [[2, 3, 4], [1,2,3], 
[4, 5,6]]})

def itemExploder(df):
    df = df.to_numpy()
    dim1, dim2, dim3 = len(df), len(df[0]), len(df[0][0])
    df2 = np.zeros((dim1, dim2, dim3), dtype=int)
    for r in range(dim1):
        for c in range(dim2):
            for i,item in enumerate(df[r][c]):
                df2[r][c][i] = item
    print(df2.shape)
    return df2

newDf = itemExploder(df)
```

This function assumes you have the same number of elements(20) in each cell.